# Entity Framework exception from query. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this contex

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

No sure why I'm getting this error running this query below

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'YogaBandy2017.Models.Profile.YogaProfile'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

```
var requestedEvents = dbContext.YogaSpaceEvents
  .Where(i => i.RequestedInstructor == yogaProfile)
  .OrderByDescending(i => i.EventDateTime)
  .Select(i => new PendingEvent
  {
      SpaceName = i.YogaSpace.Overview.Title,
      SpaceImage = i.YogaSpace.YogaSpaceImages
                      .Where(j => j.IsMainImage)
                      .Select(j => j.ImageThumbnailCropped11)
                      .FirstOrDefault(),

      SpaceId = i.YogaSpace.YogaSpaceId,
      SpaceEventsHosted = i.YogaSpace.ClassesHosted,
      SpaceReviewNumber = i.YogaSpace.ReviewNumber,
      SpaceReviewPercent = i.YogaSpace.ReviewPercentage,
      SpaceNumberOfReviews = i.YogaSpace.NumberOfReviews,

      HostImage = i.YogaSpace.YogaProfile.YogaProfileImages
                    .Where(k => k.IsMainImage)
                    .Select(k => k.ImageThumbnailCropped)
                    .FirstOrDefault(),

      HostId = i.YogaSpace.YogaProfile.YogaProfileId,
      HostName = i.YogaSpace.YogaProfile.FirstName,

      EventDateTime = i.EventDateTime,
      Style = i.StyleMain.ToString(),
      Duration = i.Duration,

      EventId = i.YogaSpaceEventId
  })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: So... are you using linq2sql or ef? If your question is only about ef I suggest you remove the linq2sql tag

Comment: What did you try? Without Where? using a simpler Select? Is the problem in the Where or in the Select? What statement in the Select causes the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You cant use *Entities* like that in an `Where` clause (it has no idea how to convert it to SQL)

However, most likely they will have an `Id` property. So you should be able to do the following

```
dbContext.YogaSpaceEvents.Where(i => i.RequestedInstructor.Id == yogaProfile.Id)
```

Comment: @user1186050 i hear you

Comment: @user1186050 if this answered your question make sure upvote and mark it as the correct answer for other people to find :)